# Why is it called "area of union" when calculating the Intersection over Union?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, object-detection, bounding-box, jaccard-similarity

When calculating the Intersection Over Union the following explanation is widely used.

[image]

(Source: [A Survey on Performance Metrics for Object-Detection Algorithms](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343194514_A_Survey_on_Performance_Metrics_for_Object-Detection_Algorithms), by Padilla et al. 2020)

The image and name suggest that the denominator (the area of union) is the area of both boxes combined, `box a + box b`, when in reality it's not a union but rather a symmetric difference, `box a + box b - intersection of box a and box b`.

Why is it called "area of union" and not "area of symmetric difference"?

Comment: The question aims at the denominator which is called area of union even though its not really a union when considering the union definition from the set theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these two sets $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4 \}$ and $B = \{0, 2, 3, 5, 6 \}$. Their union $A \cup B = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$. So, $|A \cup B| = 7$. The order of these numbers in $A \cup B$ does not matter, but you don't have any repeated number.

If you do $|A| + |B|$, you're effectively counting the number of elements in $A \cap B$ twice (in the example above, it would be like doing $4 + 5 = 9$, while in reality $|A \cup B| = 7$), so you subtract $|A \cap B|$ from $|A| + |B|$, i.e. $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$, where $|X|$ is the size of the set $X$.

See also [the related Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).